# How to record R Squareds of a linear regression together with the group name into a data frame in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, coefficients, coefficient-of-determination

I have a linear regression which uses cities as groups in R:

```
pop_model <- lmList(Value ~ Year | City, data = df)
```

I can make a vector of corresponding R-Squareds using this:

```
r_squareds <- summary(pop_model)$r.squared
```

But this does not give me the names of Cities. So, I don't know which R-Squared is for which regression. How can I make a table to record these R-Squareds together with their names into a dataframe to get a dataframe like this?:

City | R-Squared

Comment: They are given in the order obtained for the coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the city names from the `names` of `residuals`.

```
data <- data.frame(city = names(pop_model$residuals),
                   R_squared = pop_model$r.squared)
```

Example using `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(nlme)

pop_model <- lmList(mpg ~ am | cyl, data = mtcars)

tmp <- summary(pop_model)

data <- data.frame(cyl = names(tmp$residuals), 
                   R_squared = tmp$r.squared)

data

#  cyl   R_squared
#1   4 0.287289249
#2   6 0.281055142
#3   8 0.002464789
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Second part of your answer works. Calls on summary. However can we be sure that names from residuals are in the same order that names from R-Squared are?